# automatic resizing of jbutton icon in gridlayout

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, image-resizing

I'm making a chess game. I'm using a gridLayout(8,8) and filled it with a JButton[8][8]. Each JButton has an icon of the piece on that square or an icon of a blank square if no piece is on it. Right now the pieces get cut off. How do I make it so that the icons automatically resize themselves to fit whatever size the grid makes the JButton?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you tried searching for how to resize images in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).